How do I prove that inversion and translation are an isometry in AdS?
I am using the AdS metric in Poincare coordinates, meaning $$ds^2 = \frac{R^2}{z^2}(dz^2 + d\vec{x}^2)$$
I want to prove why inversion $x^{\mu} = \dfrac{x'^{\mu}}{x'^2}$ and translation $x'^{\mu} =x^{\mu} + b^{\mu}$ are an isometry. I am not even sure that is the correct way to write down the inversion, is it equivalent to $x'^{\mu} = \dfrac{x^{\mu}}{x^2}$? I have seen both definitions.
I have read another question here about what an isometry is(What is the physical idea of isometry of a metric?), and the answer claimed that $g'_{\mu\nu}(x') = g_{\mu\nu}(x')$. But I am not sure what that even means, I get the notation $x'$, but what is $g'_{\mu\nu}$ even considered to be? I am not sure how to start my calculations. I tried calculating this:
$$g_{\mu\nu}(x') = \frac{\partial x'^{\rho}}{\partial x^{\mu}} \frac{\partial x'^{\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}} g_{\rho \sigma}(x) = x'^4 g_{\mu \nu}(x)$$ but I am pretty sure this doesn't show anything and I don't know what to do.
Thank you.

Once upon a time I worked on a M.Sc. about AdS spaces. For several reasons I never finished it, but I have published my files on GitHub. There is one file about the symmetries.

First of all
\begin{align}
x^{\prime \mu} &= \frac{x^\mu}{x^2} \quad (1) \\
x^{\mu} &= \frac{x^{\prime \mu}}{x^{\prime 2}} \quad (2)
\end{align}
are definitely equivalent because (1) implies $x^{\prime 2} = 1/x^2$.
Next, an isometry just needs to satisfy $g_{\mu\nu}(x') = g_{\mu\nu}(x)$ so translation clearly works. Showing this for inversion requires more calculation but one can either do this exercise or embed AdS in a higher dimensional space where the isometries become manifest.
